# CherryPy WebService not returning NLTK collocations to browser window

Tags: python, nltk, cherrypy

I have a very simple CherryPy webservice that I hope will be the foundation of a larger project, however, I need to get NLTK to work the way I want.

My python script imports NLTK and uses the collocation (bigram) function of NLTK, to do some analysis on pre-loaded data.

I have a couple of questions:

1) Why is the program not returning the collocations to my browser, but only to my console?.

2) Why if I am specifying `from nltk.book import text4`, the program imports the whole set of sample books (text1 to text9)?

Please, keep in mind that I am a newbie, so the answer might be in front of me, but I don't see it.

Main question: How do I pass the collocation results to the browser (webservice), instead of console?

Thanks

```
import cherrypy
import nltk
from nltk.book import text4

class BiGrams:
    def index(self):
        return text4.collocations(num=20)
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(BiGrams())
```

Comment: Possible answer to #2: when you import nltk does that already include text1 - text9?  I haven't used nltk much, but I used to work with the guy who wrote it.

Comment: As far as I know, importing NLTK does not import the books.

Comment: Regarding #2, having looked at the code (http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/nltk/book.py), importing nltk.book just loads each text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that what you get back from the `collocations()` call is not a string, and that you need to serialize it. Try this instead:

```
import cherrypy
import nltk
from nltk.book import text4
import simplejson

class BiGrams:
    def index(self):
        c = text4.collocations(num=20)
        return simplejson.dumps(c)
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(BiGrams())
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  NLTK is intended for interactive exploration of corpora and a call to collocations just dumps results to stdout.

Comment: There's not much you can do then in a threaded webserver. You could try rerouting stdout to a StringIO or file, but that wouldn't be threadsafe. You could try to replace stdout with a threadlocal file-like object, which I'll leave as an exercise for an adventurous soul in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have been doing some work with *Moby Dick* and I stumbled on the answer to the question of importing just *one* specific text the other day:

```
>>>import nltk.corpus
>>>from nltk.text import Text
>>>moby = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
```

Thus, all you really need is the fileid in order to assign the text of that file to your new Text object. Be careful, though, because only "literary" sources are in the gutenberg.words directory.

Anyway, for help with finding file ids for gutenberg, after import nltk.corpus above, you can use the following command:

```
>>> nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()

['austen-emma.txt', 'austen-persuasion.txt', 'austen-sense.txt', 'bible-kjv.txt',     'blake-poems.txt', 'bryant-stories.txt', 'burgess-busterbrown.txt', 'carroll-alice.txt',   'chesterton-ball.txt', 'chesterton-brown.txt', 'chesterton-thursday.txt', 'edgeworth-parents.txt', 'melville-moby_dick.txt', 'milton-paradise.txt', 'shakespeare-caesar.txt', 'shakespeare-hamlet.txt', 'shakespeare-macbeth.txt', 'whitman-leaves.txt']
```

This still doesn't answer the question for your specific corpus, the inaugural addresses, however. For that answer, I found this MIT paper: http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/fall2012/nltk/ch2-3.pdf

(I recommend it to anyone beginning to work with nltk texts because it talks about grabbing all kinds of textual data for analysis). The answer to getting the inaugural address fileids comes on page 6 (edited a bit):

```
>>> nltk.corpus.inaugural.fileids()
['1789-Washington.txt', '1793-Washington.txt', '1797-Adams.txt', '1801-Jefferson.txt', '1805-Jefferson.txt', '1809-Madison.txt', '1813-Madison.txt', '1817-Monroe.txt', '1821-Monroe.txt', '1825-Adams.txt', '1829-Jackson.txt', '1833-Jackson.txt', '1837-VanBuren.txt', '1841-Harrison.txt', '1845-Polk.txt', '1849-Taylor.txt', '1853-Pierce.txt', '1857-Buchanan.txt', '1861-Lincoln.txt', '1865-Lincoln.txt', '1869-Grant.txt', '1873-Grant.txt', '1877-Hayes.txt', '1881-Garfield.txt', '1885-Cleveland.txt', '1889-Harrison.txt', '1893-Cleveland.txt', '1897-McKinley.txt', '1901-McKinley.txt', '1905-Roosevelt.txt', '1909-Taft.txt', '1913-Wilson.txt', '1917-Wilson.txt', '1921-Harding.txt', '1925-Coolidge.txt', '1929-Hoover.txt', '1933-Roosevelt.txt', '1937-Roosevelt.txt', '1941-Roosevelt.txt', '1945-Roosevelt.txt', '1949-Truman.txt', '1953-Eisenhower.txt', '1957-Eisenhower.txt', '1961-Kennedy.txt', '1965-Johnson.txt', '1969-Nixon.txt', '1973-Nixon.txt', '1977-Carter.txt', '1981-Reagan.txt', '1985-Reagan.txt', '1989-Bush.txt', '1993-Clinton.txt', '1997-Clinton.txt', '2001-Bush.txt', '2005-Bush.txt', '2009-Obama.txt']
```

Thus, you should be able to import specific inaugural addresses as Texts (assuming you did "from nltk.text import Text" above) or you can work with them using the "inaugural" identifier imported above. For example, this works:

```
>>>address1 = Text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('2009-Obama.txt'))
```

In fact, you can treat all inaugural addresses as one document by calling inaugural.words without any arguments, as in the following example from [this page](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/corpus.html):

```
>>>len(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words())
```

OR

> > > addresses = Text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words())

I remembered reading this thread a month ago when trying to answer this question myself, so perhaps this information, if coming late, will be helpful to someone somewhere.

(This is my first contribution to Stack Overflow. I've been reading for months and never had anything useful to add until now. Just want to say generally 'thanks to everyone for all the help.')

Comment: "This still doesn't answer the question for your specific corpus, the inaugural addresses". Please, read my question carefully, I never ask anything about inaugural addresses. You are confusing your answers, but than you anyway.

Comment: When you wrote above that you were running the following command, `from nltk.book import text4`, I assumed that you were attempting to assign "text4" to some object that you could then use. Text4 in the nltk.book schema is "text4: Inaugural Address Corpus" as confirmed by reading the Google Code book: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch01.html
It's possible you have no idea what text you are trying to import or why you're importing it?

Comment: my question dealt with cherrypy webservice not displaying the results of ANY nltk.book in the browser, but in the console. Although, I have not coded your answer, after careful review of the logic, it seems to be correct and simpler than replacing stdout with a threadlocal file-like object suggested somewhere here. I solved this issue long time ago in my project (I never intended to use the NLTK corpus in my project), but it always bothered that I couldn't get to output collocation of any nltk.book to a webservice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code (http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/) and you'll learn a lot (I know I did).

1) Collocations is returning to your console because that's what it is supposed to do.

```
help(text4.collocations)
```

will give you:

```
Help on method collocations in module nltk.text:

collocations(self, num=20, window_size=2) method of nltk.text.Text instance
    Print collocations derived from the text, ignoring stopwords.

    @seealso: L{find_collocations}
    @param num: The maximum number of collocations to print.
    @type num: C{int}
    @param window_size: The number of tokens spanned by a collocation (default=2)
    @type window_size: C{int}
```

Browse the source in text.py and you'll find the method for collocations is pretty straight-forward.

2) Importing nltk.book loads each text. You could could just grab the bits you need from book.py and write a method that only loads the inaugural addresses.

Comment: Spaceghost: Thank you for you comments. I dont have any problem with the results of the collocation function: it is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. My problem is that I can't pass the results to a client, using the simple CherryPy webservice I created, and I don't have enough knowledge of python/webservices to fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the function writes to the console and does not return anything.  Follow the link I gave you to see the code which you can then borrow to make a version which returns the results in a variable instead of writing to the console